# Exit Code -1 when executing psake task

Tags: powershell, build-script, psake

I have a psake task that I run from my build script to verify that the expected artifacts are created in the expected location.  It seems to work when I run it from the command line, however it is returning an error code of "-1" when the assert passes or fails.  What does exit code -1 mean and why wouldn't I get an exit code of 0 when it passes the assertion?

```
task VerifyArtifacts {
    Assert (Test-Path $package_file) "$package_file could not be found"
}
```

Command to execute:

```
psake .\default.ps1 VerifyArtifacts
```